# Parse string to date with moment.js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I want to parse the following string with moment.js **2014-02-27T10:00:00** and output
day month year (14 march 2014)
I have been reading the docs but without success
http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/now/

Answer (score 283, accepted):

You need to use the `.format()` function.

`MM` - Month number

`MMM` - Month word

```
var date = moment("2014-02-27T10:00:00").format('DD-MM-YYYY');
var dateMonthAsWord = moment("2014-02-27T10:00:00").format('DD-MMM-YYYY');
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dceast/PAc3j/1/)**

Comment: What about existing date variables.

`var date = moment("2014-02-27T10:00:00").format('DD-MM-YYYY');
var dateCalendarPart = moment(date).format('YYYY/MM/DD');
alert(date);
alert(dateCalendarPart);`
Gives an invalid date error?????

Comment: try ''var dateCalendarPart = moment(date,'YYYY/MM/DD'); alert(date); ''

Comment: @AndrewDay ... `"01-02-2017"`, "January 2" or "February 1" ? Momentjs can't read your mind.

Comment: This answer only works because the OP's string is in a standard Date format. Stephen Paul's answer shows how to convert any string, given a specific format, to a date that can be manipulated.

Comment: It returns string not a date as OP asked. Weird it gets upvotes.

Comment: ```.format()``` return a string, he is asking to get Date object from string

Answer (score 615):

I always seem to find myself landing here only to realize that the title and question are not quite aligned.

**If you want a [moment date](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/) from a string**:

```
const myMomentObject = moment(str, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

From [moment documentation](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/):

> Instead of modifying the native Date.prototype, Moment.js creates a wrapper for the Date object.

**If you instead want a [javascript Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object from a string**:

```
const myDate = moment(str, 'YYYY-MM-DD').toDate();
```

Comment: Yep, only this one  answers. Parsing string to date (meaning input is str, out is date)

Comment: excellent answer, thank you very much as this solved my issue. I needed the JavaScript date object

Answer (score 31):

No need for moment.js to parse the input since its format is the standard one :

```
var date = new Date('2014-02-27T10:00:00');
var formatted = moment(date).format('D MMMM YYYY');
```

http://es5.github.io/#x15.9.1.15

Comment: That's the truth, no need for moment.js if you have a ISO date string... You could also use [Date.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) to be more clear that you're working with ISO strings (since the constructor can take other formats)

Comment: Doesn't work in IE8... What a surprise... Gives `NaN`.

Comment: @JuanMendes, your link says, that `Date.parse` calls `new Date`, so it should not make a difference.

Answer (score 9):

moment was perfect for what I needed. NOTE it ignores the hours and minutes and just does it's thing if you let it. This was perfect for me as my API call brings back the date and time but I only care about the date.

```
function momentTest() {

  var varDate = "2018-01-19 18:05:01.423";
  var myDate =  moment(varDate,"YYYY-MM-DD").format("DD-MM-YYYY");
  var todayDate = moment().format("DD-MM-YYYY");  
  var yesterdayDate = moment().subtract(1, 'days').format("DD-MM-YYYY");   
  var tomorrowDate = moment().add(1, 'days').format("DD-MM-YYYY");

  alert(todayDate);

  if (myDate == todayDate) {
    alert("date is today");
  } else if (myDate == yesterdayDate) {
    alert("date is yesterday");
  } else if (myDate == tomorrowDate) {
    alert("date is tomorrow");
  } else {
    alert("It's not today, tomorrow or yesterday!");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

- How to change any string date to object date (also with moment.js):

`let startDate = "2019-01-16T20:00:00.000";
 let endDate = "2019-02-11T20:00:00.000";
 let sDate = new Date(startDate);
 let eDate = new Date(endDate);`

- with moment.js:

`startDate = moment(sDate);
 endDate = moment(eDate);`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try the Intl polyfill for IE8 or the olyfill service ?

or

https://github.com/andyearnshaw/Intl.js/

Comment: Internet Explorer is no longer.

Comment: oh how i dream of this privilege

Answer (score 0):

moment("2020-01-01").utc().format('DD-MM-YYYY')

moment().format();     // 2013-02-04T10:35:24-08:00
moment.utc().format(); // 2013-02-04T18:35:24+00:00

Is giving the correct output for me, where "2020-01-01" can be any date even in datetime format will also work.