# How to split the date in JavaScript for different format

Tags: javascript, date

How to convert the following 1. 7. 2015 16:25 into date and time format using javascript?

In the below mentioned image how to convert the these two values in to datetime with the following pattern

Day.month.year Hour:minute:second;

Comment: Which image? What time zone? Have you tried anything yet that gives some results? Are you merely looking for code help? Try to read up a bit and see what you find http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7151543/convert-dd-mm-yyyy-string-to-date

Comment: Do you receive "1. 7. 2015 16:25" as a text string and want to isolate day, month, year, hour and minute?

Comment: Try to use moment.js http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22184747/parse-string-to-date-with-moment-js

Comment: Using `Date.parse()` might be your best bet. But I'd do some reading to be sure.

Comment: what is your image? what do you want to convert from "1. 7. 2015 16:25" into what?? basically what is your input and expected output?

Comment: You parse out the components (month, day, year, hour etc) and construct a Date object using the long Date constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Use moment JS
https://momentjs.com/

```
function momentTest() {

  var varDate = "2018-01-19 18:05:01.423";
  var myDate =  moment(varDate,"YYYY-MM-DD").format("DD-MM-YYYY");
  var todayDate = moment().format("DD-MM-YYYY");  
  var yesterdayDate = moment().subtract(1, 'days').format("DD-MM-YYYY");   
  var tomorrowDate = moment().add(1, 'days').format("DD-MM-YYYY");

  alert(todayDate);

  if (myDate == todayDate) {
    alert("date is today");
  } else if (myDate == yesterdayDate) {
    alert("date is yesterday");
  } else if (myDate == tomorrowDate) {
    alert("date is tomorrow");
  } else {
    alert("It's not today, tomorrow or yesterday!");
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
function toTimeZone(time, zone) {
    var format = 'YYYY/MM/DD HH:mm:ss ZZ';
    return moment(time, format).tz(zone).format(format);
}
```

this works only if you're using moment.js.

Comment: you must mention what you're using (moment.js) and how this code snippet will solve his problem with a proper description rather than posting any code samples. please read StackOverFlow help guide.