# How to sort date array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have below array of dates and I want to sort it in acceding order. I tried but not getting the positive result.

```
var arr = [ [ '02/13/2015', 0.096 ],
  [ '11/15/2013', 0.189 ],
  [ '05/15/2014', 0.11 ],
  [ '12/13/2013', 0.1285 ],
  [ '01/15/2013', 0.12 ],
  [ '01/15/2014', 0.11 ],
  [ '02/14/2014', 0.11 ],
  [ '03/14/2014', 0.11 ],
  [ '01/15/2015', 0.096 ],
  [ '07/15/2015', 0.096 ],
  [ '04/15/2013', 0.12 ],
  [ '04/15/2014', 0.11 ],
  [ '05/15/2013', 0.12 ],
  [ '06/14/2013', 0.12 ],
  [ '06/16/2014', 0.11 ],
  [ '07/15/2013', 0.12 ],
  [ '07/15/2014', 0.11 ],
  [ '03/16/2015', 0.096 ]]
```

**My Code**

```
arr.sort(function(a,b){
  return new Date(a[0][0]) - new Date(b[0][0]);
});
```

Comment: For starters, `a` is an array like `[ '11/15/2013', 0.189 ]` so `a[0][0]` would result in `'1'`.. This still requires work, however because `new Date(a[0])` - eg `new Date('11/15/2013')` - is ill-defined behavior. I recommend [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) to deal with this situation, but one can manually parse the date and use `new Date(y, m, d)` as well: there are no shortages of such examples when asking how to turn a string into a Date

Comment: For how to *"properly"* create a Date, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619202/converting-string-to-date-in-js , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22184747/parse-string-to-date-with-moment-js , etc

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are taking the first character in the date strings, converting them to `Date` instances and using them for comparison.

But, you should actually use the Date strings as they are, convert them to `Date` instances and compare them.

```
arr.sort(function (a, b) {
  return new Date(a[0]) - new Date(b[0]);
});
```

**Output**

```
[ [ '01/15/2013', 0.12 ],
  [ '04/15/2013', 0.12 ],
  [ '05/15/2013', 0.12 ],
  [ '06/14/2013', 0.12 ],
  [ '07/15/2013', 0.12 ],
  [ '11/15/2013', 0.189 ],
  [ '12/13/2013', 0.1285 ],
  [ '01/15/2014', 0.11 ],
  [ '02/14/2014', 0.11 ],
  [ '03/14/2014', 0.11 ],
  [ '04/15/2014', 0.11 ],
  [ '05/15/2014', 0.11 ],
  [ '06/16/2014', 0.11 ],
  [ '07/15/2014', 0.11 ],
  [ '01/15/2015', 0.096 ],
  [ '02/13/2015', 0.096 ],
  [ '03/16/2015', 0.096 ],
  [ '07/15/2015', 0.096 ] ]
```

Comment: FWIW, see my comment on the main post. Passing in a locale-specific string to the Date constructor ill-defined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Heavily inspired from MDN [Sorting with map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#Sorting_with_map). It is important for larger data sets.

```js
var arr = [
    ['02/13/2015', 0.096],
    ['11/15/2013', 0.189],
    ['05/15/2014', 0.11],
    ['12/13/2013', 0.1285],
    ['01/15/2013', 0.12],
    ['01/15/2014', 0.11],
    ['02/14/2014', 0.11],
    ['03/14/2014', 0.11],
    ['01/15/2015', 0.096],
    ['07/15/2015', 0.096],
    ['04/15/2013', 0.12],
    ['04/15/2014', 0.11],
    ['05/15/2013', 0.12],
    ['06/14/2013', 0.12],
    ['06/16/2014', 0.11],
    ['07/15/2013', 0.12],
    ['07/15/2014', 0.11],
    ['03/16/2015', 0.096]
];

// temporary array holds objects with position and sort-value
var mapped = arr.map(function (el, i) {
    var d = el[0].split('/');
    return { index: i, value: new Date(d[2], d[0] - 1, d[1]) };
})

// sorting the mapped array containing the reduced values
mapped.sort(function (a, b) {
    return +(a.value > b.value) || +(a.value === b.value) - 1;
});

// container for the resulting order
var result = mapped.map(function (el) {
    return arr[el.index];
});

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: For historical purposes the month should be 0..11

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is sorting only by the dates, I think this code would help:

```
arr.sort(function(a,b){return new Date(a[0]) - new Date(b[0]);});
```