# how to convert a date string '13.04.2015' into JavaScript Date object

Tags: javascript

how can I convert a date string

```
'13.04.2015'
```

into JavaScript Date object in a performant way?

Comment: take a look at this post, using moment.js http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22184747/parse-string-to-date-with-moment-js

Comment: why you would care about perfomrance? do you want to parse more than 1 date? all solutions so far take less than 1ms: https://jsfiddle.net/q6vb1m64/1/

Answer (score 2):

Try this parser:

```
var dateString = '13.04.2015';
var myDate = new Date(dateString.split('.').reverse());
```

Check the [demo](http://jsbin.com/vecixopico/1/edit?js,console).

Comment: Cool solution, I like it

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
var str = '13.04.2015',
    dateParts = str.split('.'),
    year = dateParts[2],
    month = dateParts[1],
    day = dateParts[0],
    yourDate = new Date([year, month, day]);
```

[JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/5b3Lhep6/)

Also if need to work a lot with dates, I would recomend you [MomentJs Library](http://momentjs.com/)

Code with it will look like:

```
moment('13.04.2015', 'DD.MM.YYYY')
```

[JSFiddle example moment](https://jsfiddle.net/FLhpq/3778/)

Answer (score 0):

```
new Date( "13.04.2015".replace( /(\d{2}).(\d{2}).(\d{4})/, "$2/$1/$3") );
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cyspid/5khLL995/2/)