# Moment JS convert friendly date to JS date

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I'm using Moment JS to try and convert a human readable date into something more useful for a computer/JS to understand, given the following Strings as example, my Moment JS doesn't appear to convert them:

```js
const exampleDate = '1st January 2019'
moment(exampleDate).format('DD-MM-YYYY')
```

It returns `Invalid Date`, why?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parse string to date with moment.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22184747/parse-string-to-date-with-moment-js)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to "tell" moment from which format you want to create a date (second argument).

```
const exampleDate = '1st January 2019'
moment(exampleDate, 'Do MMMM YYYY').format('DD-MM-YYYY');
```

[Link to JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rcm9jopL/2/)

Comment: Since the date is `'1st'`, you should use `Do` instead of `DD`.

Comment: Yes, you're right, but moment will still parse it just fine if there is only one space between day and month e.g. "1LongStringHere January". I'll update my answer to not cause confusion, thanks.