# how to do the date conversion in moment.js using javascript?

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs, datetime-format

Here is my date string and i want to convert this into javascript date object.

Input: -- Wednesday, March 4th, 2020, 5:00:00 pm

Expected result: -- 2020-03-13T15:04:16.913Z'

I tried :

```
moment('Wednesday, March 4th, 2020, 5:00:00 pm').format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss\\Z')
```

Comment: Please show the code you have tried

Comment: Well, your expected result is a bit different than your input, isn't it? 5:00:00pm => 15;04:16.913Z? I can see the two hours being a time zone difference, but 4:16.913? Never heard of a nanosecond-level offset for a time zone...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22184747/parse-string-to-date-with-moment-js

Comment: here is my code:  moment('Wednesday, March 4th, 2020, 5:00:00 pm').format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss\\Z')

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting a string to a date in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5619202/converting-a-string-to-a-date-in-javascript)

Comment: Wednesday, March 4th, 2020, 5:00:00 pm i want to convert this string how it is possible

Answer (score 0):

You need to inform Moment about the format of the string you're giving it.

From the [documentation / display](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/) :

```
Wednesday = dddd
March = MMMM
4th = Qo
2020 = YYYY
5:00:00 pm = h:mm:ss a
```

So yout input format is `"dddd, MMMM Qo, YYYY, h:mm:ss a"`

Now you can create a valid Moment and manipulate it.

```
moment('Wednesday, March 4th, 2020, 5:00:00 pm', "dddd, MMMM Qo, YYYY, h:mm:ss a").format(whatever)
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to inform moment the format of the expected input , followed by format() to convert the same into required format.

Based on their docs: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/

Check this code out. It will help you get started:

```js
var input = "Wednesday, March 4th, 2020, 5:00:00 pm";
var date = moment(input, "dddd, MMMM Do, YYYY, h:mm:SSSS a").format(
  "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss\\Z"
);
console.log(date);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```