# How to validate date format only for dd.mm.yyyy using regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm validating the date format as DD.MM.YYYY using the regex 
`^(\d{2}).\d{2}.(\d{4})$`.

Unfortunately this is not working in the following scenarios.

```
 02:02:200 -> still gives as valid date even though used  :
 33.33.3333 -> still gives as validate even though there is no 33 date and month etc.
```

What is the correct regex for DD.MM.YYYY?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regex to validate date format dd/mm/yyyy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15491894/regex-to-validate-date-format-dd-mm-yyyy)

Answer (score 2):

If you need to check for something, like 31-st of June (non-existent) or 29-th of February in a non-leap year, you would need something more sophisticated than simple RegExp:

```js
const test1 = '02:02:200',
      test2 = '33.33.3333',
      
      validate = dateStr => {
        const [dd, mm, yyyy] = dateStr.split('.'),
              date = new Date(yyyy, +mm-1, dd)
        return  date.getFullYear() == yyyy &&
                date.getMonth() == mm-1 &&
                date.getDate() == dd
      }
      
console.log(test1, validate(test1))
console.log(test2, validate(test2))
console.log('21.06.1982', validate('21.06.1982'))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%;}
```

Comment: It is not working when I pass wrong year  validate (02.06.20229) also needs restrict DD.MM.YYYY length.

Comment: @klmuralimohan : did my answer solved your question or you're still looking for some better options?

Answer (score 0):

To be able to validate this using a regex you'd have to base the day range on what month it is, and if it's a leap year, or if it was during a time when calendars changed, and some dates were skipped, or added; this depending on locale.

You're better off using some date lib and ask it if the string can be parsed to a proper date.

See this answer for example how to do it with Moment.js https://stackoverflow.com/a/22184830/108804

Comment: I would say, such a simple task is not worth neither building a mind cracking regexp nor attaching some library (for this purpose only) with date parsing feature . [Few simple lines](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61868501/11299053) may do the trick pretty easily.

Comment: I agree! It seems I stopped reading the docs after "It is not recommended to use Date.parse as until ES5..." didn't bother to understand it :)
Well, we agree that this isn't a job for regex, which was my main concern.