# Convert String Format to Date Format JS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have one String-formatted Datetime.

I want to give an error if a value has been selected in the 12-hour interval after the current date. However, I do not know how to change data.

I used the following line of code.

```
// this.startDate0 = Input value (string) (Value: 31/07/2020 20:00)
console.log(Date.parse(this.startDate0)); // Maybe NaN maybe 1581099600000
```

I did not understand how to do it, can you help?

Comment: why is the first line commented out?

Comment: Please show example of the startDate value?

Comment: Could you please give the string you used. It probably is giving you milliseconds.

Comment: Coming through Vue Data, I have made you a comment line for information purposes. It normally comes as data.

Comment: @NoahStahl Now edited code line. (Value: 31/07/2020 20:00) Example..

Comment: The problem is you are providing javascript with a already formated date / time. Provide it in ISO format and format it later, it will fit best.

Comment: I recommend you to use moment js, which has more options for formats and conversions. Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22184747/parse-string-to-date-with-moment-js#answer-44134515. moment js can be added through npm install moment

Answer (score 1):

If you're open to using a library, I'd suggest using the [date-fns parse](https://date-fns.org/v2.15.0/docs/parse) function. Supply the expected pattern as a parameter and it will parse the value. You can then use the helper [differenceInHours](https://date-fns.org/v2.15.0/docs/differenceInHours) method to compare with 12 hours from present.

Comment: Hello, i not want using other library. Thanks for comment.